# how to calculate count of mode with aggregation functions in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, analysis

how can I calculate **count of mode** with an aggregation function in oracle.

I mean something like this:

my data:

```
table1:
CITY        JOB
++++++++++++++++++++++
Toronto     Programmer
Vancouver   Manager
Vancouver   Manager
Vancouver   Tester
Vancouver   Tester
Vancouver   Tester
Vancouver   Tester
New York    Manager
New York    Manager
New York    Manager
New York    Tester
```

My desire query:

```
 select city,  
        stats_mode(job) sm,  
        x(job) count_of_stats_mode
 from table1
```

result:

```
city       sm           count_of_stats_mode
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Toronto    Programmer   1
Vancouver  Tester       4
New York   Manager      3
```

I need **x** that is a function 
just I don't want to use subquery

Comment: Why don't you want to use a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a way of doing this without a subquery:

```
select city, job, cnt
from (select city, job, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by city order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table1
      group by city, job
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

This isn't pretty, but I think this does what you want without a subquery:

```
select distinct city,
       max(job) keep (dense_rank first order by count(*) desc) over (partition by city) as mode_job,
       max(count(*)) over (partition by city) as mode_cnt
from table1
group by city, job;
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not answer. I think about "select count(case when stats_mode(job)=job then 1 end) from ..." but nested group by is not allowed.

Comment: @parvij . . . The second query *is* an answer to your question, which gets the mode and the count without a subquery.  The version in your comment doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CITY, JOB, COUNT(CITY) AS count_of_stats_mode
FROM table1
GROUP BY CITY, JOB
```